# Native Client use outside of the Chrome App Store

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I have successfully created a Native Client app that works using localhost and works once posted to the Chrome App Store.

I now need to find a way to embed this app in a web page outside of the App Store, which currently fails.

I've read that the usage of the nacl_io and specifically sockets is ONLY accessible when published via the Chrome App Store?

I also came across this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps (I know it's essentially discontinued). Is there a replacement that could work? Or is it just the Chrome App Store?

The `<embed>` tag is mentioned here (https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/application-structure). Am I right in saying even if we got this to load the .hmf file and communicate with the .pexe that it would still fail when using sockets due to the application not being passed through the Chrome App Store?

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket access is only allowed for applications in the Chrome Web Store. Similarly, Native Client applications (e.g. using a .nexe file) are also only allowed on the Chrome Web Store.

You can run a Portable Native Client (PNaCl) application on the open web, but it will not have access to the socket API.

nacl_io is still available to use. It's only the socket API that will fail if you try to use it.

You can still use the [URLLoader](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/cpp/classpp_1_1_u_r_l_loader.html) and [WebSocket](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/cpp/classpp_1_1_web_socket.html) APIs, though. Perhaps these will be enough for your application?

Comment: Therefore if you need to distribute a portable app as part of large cloud based ‘hosted App’ enterprise class solution, how is that accomplished?

Comment: PNaCl executables can be hosted on any web server, including whatever server you're using to host your cloud-based enterprise app.

Comment: But sockets still won't be useable?

Comment: No, TCP/UDP sockets are only allowed for Chrome Apps installed from the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: We have our Chrome App in the Web Store, which works. But how do we then host that app on our own web site?

Comment: IIRC, a Chrome App that uses sockets cannot be a hosted app (e.g. a web site). You can make it easy for Chrome users to install the app from your website, though: take a look at inline installation: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation